# Json date format in condition query to check current date

Tags: json, linq, datetime, indexing, ravendb

How can I convert date time here. The date time coming from the database (RDate) is in Json format "/Date(1323975591369)/" and I am comparing with DateTime.Today

```
 int count = session.Query<Movies>("Movie/CurrentList")   
                    .Where(x => x.RDate== DateTime.Today)
                    .Count();
```

Right now even though there are records that match the condition, I am showing zero result in count.

Answer (score 1):

ZVenue, you probably want to query only the Date component of your *RDate* property. If that is the case, just extend your query properly.

However, I'm not sure you get the basics right, so I've put together a small sample application. Pretty boring in fact, but I hope it helps:

```
class Movie
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var documentStore = new DocumentStore { Url = "http://localhost:8080/" })
        {
            documentStore.Initialize();

            //SeedData(documentStore);

            using (var documentSession = documentStore.OpenSession())
            {
                var movies = documentSession.Query<Movie>()
                    .Where(x => x.Date.Date == new DateTime(2011, 6, 2))
                    .ToList();

                foreach (var movie in movies)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name: {0}", movie.Name));
                }
            }
        }

        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void SeedData(IDocumentStore documentStore)
    {
        var movies = new Movie[]
                         {
                             new Movie {Name = "May", Date = new DateTime(2011, 5, 1)},
                             new Movie {Name = "June", Date = new DateTime(2011, 6, 1)},
                             new Movie {Name = "June2a", Date = new DateTime(2011, 6, 2)},
                             new Movie {Name = "June2b", Date = new DateTime(2011, 6, 2)},
                             new Movie {Name = "June2c", Date = new DateTime(2011, 6, 2, 5, 0, 0)},
                             new Movie {Name = "June2d", Date = new DateTime(2011, 6, 2, 6, 0, 0)},
                             new Movie {Name = "June3", Date = new DateTime(2011, 6, 3)},
                             new Movie {Name = "July", Date = new DateTime(2011, 7, 1)},
                         };

        using (var documentSession = documentStore.OpenSession())
        {
            foreach (var movie in movies)
            {
                documentSession.Store(movie);
            }

            documentSession.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```